# Convert HTML Character Back to Text Using Java Standard Library

Tags: java, html, html-entities

I would like to convert some HTML characters back to text using Java Standard Library. I was wondering whether any library would achieve my purpose?

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    // "Happy & Sad" in HTML form.
    String s = "Happy &amp; Sad";
    System.out.println(s);

    try {
        // Change to "Happy & Sad". DOESN'T WORK!
        s = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think the Apache Commons Lang library's `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3()` and `unescapeHtml4()` methods are what you are looking for. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html.

Comment: Up to date url: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but what the OP was asking for was how to translate between HTML entities and "plain" text (which is ASCII for me, but YMMV). The Jakarta lib above has unescapeHTML (and escapeHTML), which does the trick.  URLDecoder still works for percent-encoding URL strings (like GET parameters).

Comment: How same will support in case of Android, any idea?

Comment: Better to give the main url, the specific versions can be deleted ;) => http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: StringEscapeUtils is deprecated. The reply just below is now the most correct.

Comment: No offense, I'm a fervent Apache commons supported and an Apache Fundation Software member but I agree wth allemattio. From experience I'd rather use jsoup as suggested below.

Comment: You please add the *gradle implementation* for the next beacuse i almost can fount that.

implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.0'

Answer (score 28):

Here you have to just add jar file in lib jsoup in your application and then use this code.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Encoder {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = Jsoup.parse("&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;").text();
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Link to download jsoup: http://jsoup.org/download

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  No other library is faster nor easier to import than the amazing Jsoup.

Comment: Awesome.  This is answer.

Answer (score 7):

[`java.net.URLDecoder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) deals only with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format (e.g. "%20" represents space), not with [HTML character entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html). I don't think there's anything on the Java platform for that. You could write your own utility class to do the conversion, like [this one](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/src/org/freeshell/zs/common/HtmlManipulator.java.html).

Answer (score 5):

The URL decoder should only be used for decoding strings from the urls generated by html forms which are in the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" mime type. This does not support html characters.

After a [search](http://www.google.com/search?&q=html+entities+decoding+java) I found a [Translate](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/util/Translate.html) class within the [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: very good library, now it's easy to do something like <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs#L316>

Answer (score 4):

You can use the class org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils:

```
String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("Happy &amp; Sad")
```

It is working.

Comment: I prefer this solution. When possible I suggest using Apache libs. (my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to do it using the standard library. But I do know and use this class that deals with html entities.

> *"HTMLEntities is an Open Source Java class that contains a collection of static methods (htmlentities, unhtmlentities, ...) to convert special and extended characters into HTML entitities and vice versa."*

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=htmlentities

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use unescapeHtml4:

```
    String miCadena="GU&#205;A TELEF&#211;NICA";
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(miCadena));
```

This code print the line:
GUÍA TELEFÓNICA

Answer (score 1):

As @jem suggested, it is possible to use jsoup.

With jSoup 1.8.3 it il possible to use the method *Parser.unescapeEntities* that retain the original html.

```
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
...
String html = Parser.unescapeEntities(original_html, false);
```

It seems that in some previous release this method is not present.