# Problem of accent between MySQL and Java application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, blob

i have an application with use Hibernate and Mysql. In Mysql i have a blob in my table.
When i record a value in this table with accent like é or è in mysql i have a good result (binary) so when i want read into my jsp i have ? instead of é

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably use accented characters in HTML. You should actually use [HTML character codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). I believe this is due to interpretation of the characters by the browser.

Have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library) which suggests a java library to handle this kind of stuff.

Comment: can i use this in my jdbc url ..?
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: @Mercer it might if your JSP also sends a header stating it's UTF-8 so the browser knows how to interpret it. I believe that might just be more work, and less reliable, than converting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong response encoding? Do you use the following directive in your JSPs?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: i use this in my jsp
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />