# How to write special character ( &, <,> etc ) in xml using dom parser

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to create an xml file which have '&' in one of its text node. like

```
<url>www.sample.com/where/values?firstvalue=1&secondvalue=2</url>
```

Now what I am getting is

```
<url>www.sample.com/where/values?firstvalue=1&amp;secondvalue=2</url>
```

Could you please let me know how can I achieve that. I am attaching the url value to dom using `contenturl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(model.getDocURL()));`

and I am parsing using following method

```
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");    
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: If you *serialise* the DOM in the first form, you will have a non well-formed XML document, and XML processors will be unable to read it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `&amp;` on your node; `&` is a reserved character and needs to be encoded on your XML output. If you read that string as XML (i.e., through a XML parser), everything will be fine.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know why you would want to create poorly formed xml.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am totaly agree with you that it would be a poorely formed XML but this is a management request and I can not do anything ... they want in that format so I am requesting that with you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Rubens Farias that you probably want to leave it as `&amp;` which is a correctly escaped ampersand. However this question deals with unescaping html characters:

[Convert HTML Character Back to Text Using Java Standard Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried escaping the ampersand character as 
"...firstvalue=1\&#x0Dsecondvalue=2..."  ?

Comment: 1. His request is to create poorly formed xml. 2. Even if his goal were reasonable, that answer doesn't get him any closer.