# Html get title wrong encoding on åäö

Tags: java, html, get, title

I have made a small function to get the title a web page, in this case IMDB.
But when the title contains special characters, for example åäö the encoding screws up.

for example, i call the function with "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290002/"

```
im expecting the title "Familjen är värre (2004) - IMDb"
but i get: "Familjen &#xE4;r v&#xE4;rre (2004) - IMDb"

I dont know how to get the 'ä' from '&#xE4;'
```

I have tryed to use encoding: "ISO-8859-1" that imdb uses but i doesnt make a difference.

```
private String getTitleForLink(String link) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>");
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(link).openConnection();
        httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                httpcon.getInputStream(), );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while (br.ready()) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(br.readLine());
            if ((m.find() == true)) {
                String title = m.group(1);
                br.close();
                return title.trim();
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: The things like `&#xE4;` are XML entities. Try `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(link)`

Comment: The question has already been answered before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library