# Parse character entity references

Tags: java, html, replace

I made a webcrawler using Selenium and it returns the content of certain HTML elements. Now I noticed it returns things like `&nbsp;` and `&amp;`. Is there a simple way to turn these into the right character other than using the replace method for every single entity? I use the JSoup HTML parser to get rid of the unwanted HTML code that the crawler returns, but it doesn't seem to deal with this particular isssue.

Comment: If [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12614297/1016716) solves your problem, we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @MrLister It did. Thank you very much. Should I delete this question? I don't see an option to close it.