# How to print the symbols &#032; and &lt; and &gt; to a file as space < and > respectively

Tags: java, html, unicode, special-characters, nio

How do you print symbols in Java to a file when you have only the symbol description?

I received a string from DB2 which contains symbols. 
Two samples:

```
1) &lt;0800&gt;
2) 51V&#032;3801Z
```

Such a string goes to two different places. One is a JSP rendering it as HTML.  That is perfect; I get `<0800>` and `51V 3801Z`, respectively. The other place is a CSV file created with `java.io.FileWriter`, and it does not convert to "<", ">", and " ". Instead, it is printed exactly as it came from DB2:

```
&lt;0800&gt;
and 51V&#032;3801Z.
```

Is there anything the "new" nio library could help me? I have tried `apache.commons.lang3.StringScapeUtils.escapeHTML4` without success.

Comment: Try with `*un*escapeHtml4` instead of `escapeHTML4`.

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode

Comment: Pshemo, sorry, I don't know what you mean with "un*". About the uppercase in ...TML, kindly, ignore it. I just wrote escapeHTML4 instead of escapeHtml4 as typo.

Comment: I mean that `escapeHTML4` is meant to escape special characters to HTML code like `>` to `&gt;`. If you want to convert in other direction (from `&gt` to `>`) you need to use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`. If that is what you are doing [edit] your question and add that `un` part at start of the method.

Comment: If it is supposed to be plain text, why is it HTML escaped in the database? If it is supposed to be HTML, what should CSV content be when there are HTML tags, e.g. bold text such as `This is <b>bold</b>`, or a hyperlink such as `This is a <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink">link</a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking into Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)), namely the [unescapeHtml4() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)).

Example:

```
String input = "&lt;0800&gt;";
String output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(input);
```

Ensure you are using the **un**escapeHtml4 method, and not the regular escapeHtml4 method!