# How to prevent jsoup converting special characters?

Tags: java, jsoup

Please look at the following simplified example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String html = "<html>\n" +
                    " <head></head>\n" +
                    " <body>\n" +
                    "  <div> \n" +
                    "   <p> 2 <= X </p> \n" +
                    "  </div>\n" +
                    " </body>\n" +
                    "</html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);                    
        System.out.println(doc.select("p").outerHtml());
    }
```

This prints out `<p> 2 &lt;= X </p>` but i am expecting the selected html part to be printed out as it was : `<p> 2 <= X </p>`. How can i tell jsoup not to convert the '<' symbol?

Comment: Your input is not valid HTML.  Jsoup is correct to escape it for you.

Comment: I have no control over the input. Is there a way to tell jsoup to ignore validity of html and parse the document as it is to get the output wanted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to use jsoup.

With jSoup 1.8.3 it is possible to use the method [Parser.unescapeEntities](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-) that retain the original html.

```
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
...
String html = Parser.unescapeEntities(original_html, false));
```

In some previous releases this method is not present.

Read more from [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. But what does the second boolean parameter?

Comment: It seems it does not make any difference if set to true or false?

Comment: @RedSea - Please find details for boolean param https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4() for this:

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(doc.select("p").outerHtml()));
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)