# jsoup parse html tag attribute

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For Example:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body sometag='"'></body>
</html>
```

When I use Jsoup to parse this html like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

It will become

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body sometag="&quot;"></body>
</html>
```

Take notice of the ' and " , I dont't want it parsing ' and " ,I just need it to get some text
is there any way to avoid jsoup parsing this. thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186195/how-to-prevent-jsoup-converting-special-characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent jsoup converting special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186195/how-to-prevent-jsoup-converting-special-characters)

Comment: thanks @VladimirTopolev ,I tried,but I could only  convert &quot; to " , I'm asked to  let ' not change to " ,look at the attribute name, the ' became "

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use an HTML parser. Use an XML parser instead.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've played around a little bit with different String escaping and the easiest way to achieve this is to do the following:

Though this may not be what you after but we'll see.

```
String html = "<html> <head> </head> <body sometag='\"'> </body> </html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
System.out.println( StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml( doc.toString() ) );
```